# How to model foreign key references to initialise Django model using YAML

Tags: python, django, serialization, yaml

I'm trying to initialise some Django models with the following yaml code:

```
- model: app.block &block_1
  pk: 1

- model: app.vertex
  fields:
    x: 804837.500000
    y: 7508312.500000
    z: 326.000000
    block: *block_1

- model: app.vertex
  fields:
    x: 804837.500000
    y: 7508312.500000
    z: 334.000000
    block: *block_1

- model: app.vertex
  fields:
    x: 804837.500000
    y: 7508362.500000
    z: 326.000000
    block: *block_1
```

However, when calling 'python manage.py loaddata ./data.yaml' to populate the database, I get an error message saying

```
alizers/pyyaml.py", line 62, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError(e)
DeserializationError: found undefined alias 'block_1'
  in "./data/initial.yaml", line 9, column 12
```

For some reason, the anchor block_1 is not recognised. Does anyone how the anchor is properly placed? Is there anything else wrong with the yaml format?

Cheers,
Max

Update:
I tried to export the data from Django to get a feel of how the syntax is. I got this result:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata app --format=yaml
- fields: {block: 1, x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0}
  model: app.vertex
  pk: 1
- fields: {block: 2, x: 4.0, y: 5.0, z: 6.0}
  model: app.vertex
  pk: 2
- fields: {}
  model: app.block
  pk: 1
- fields: {}
  model: app.block
  pk: 2
- fields: {}
  model: app.block
  pk: 3
```

This is pretty useless. The export does not seem to capture references which are in fact existing (checked via admin interface).

I also had another go with the online parser. While it passes the parser, Django raises an exception:

```
- block:  &block_1
    model:   app.block
    pk: 1


- vertex:
    model:   app.vertex
    fields:
      x:     804837.500000
      y:     7508312.500000
      z:     326.000000
      block: *block_1
```

Caused

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 190, in handle
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 62, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError(e)
DeserializationError: 'model'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the asterisk in "*block_1" necessary? Note I'm no YAML expert, I just looked at your data in http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and http://instantyaml.appspot.com/ and removed it - maybe it is lost as a reference then?

Comment: If I remove the asterisk, the stack trace is `code`DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'app.block &block_1'`code`. There's definitely a difference to the online yaml parser. The very same code is parsed properly on the web site, but not by Django/pyyaml.

Comment: I think what happens if you remove the * is that block_1 is just interpreted as ordinary string, as opposed to a reference.